# How to find out the adjacent word pairs from a string in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a String like `good` and i want to find out the word pairs from that string such as `oo` and if String is `success` than out put should be `cc ss` without using any String's built in functions in java.
Is it possible?

Comment: No, But I just want to do this if it's possible and i tried hard but couldn't get the solution

Comment: What should the output be if there's over 2 hits: should "abbbc" return "bb" or "bbb"?

Comment: *"No,"* Rubbish it isn't *"But I just want to do this.."*  Then use a String and stop wasting time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without *any* built-in method - no. But with just one or two - you can

```
char previous = 0;
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
   if (chars[i] == previous) {
       System.out.println(previous + "" + previous);
   }
   previous = chars[i];
}
```

I would prefer `i < str.length()` and `str.charAt(i)`, but it uses more `String` methods.

Comment: Thanks but actually i need with out using string built in function.

Comment: since string does not have publicly accessible fields, you have to call at least 1 method to obtain its characters. Not possible otherwise. (apart from using reflection, but that doesn't count, I guess)

Comment: unless you represent your string as a char array initially